# Is there a way to create a Background image for DMG so that the image will fit any screen?

Tags: dmg

I'm opening a DMG on a M1 MacBookPro 13" screen (2560x1600) and the background image, which is 740x494, is not fully displayed.

Is there a rule of thumb type solution for making sure that when a DMG is opened on any macOS, the background image is fully displayed? i.e. "Use this resolution"?

Comment: Been a long time since I've needed to do this [& I've never tested on Retina], but I'm sure that you just save the dmg with the window open & correctly sized.

Answer (score 1):

## create-dmg

Use a tool such as [`create-dmg`](https://github.com/create-dmg/create-dmg) to set the window size and position on opening:

```
create-dmg --window-size 740 494 [options ...] <output_name.dmg> <source_folder>
```

For alternative tools and scripts, see [How do I create a nice-looking DMG for Mac OS X using command-line tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96882)